# AngularJS: Login/Sign Up & Multiple Updates @ the same time

Tags: angularjs

I've quick questions below related to angularjs.

1- How to achieve login/ sign up features in AngularJs like we have in facebook or different applications??

2-  I created a single page app using Angular where user can enter data using form and as soon as user enters submit button; the new data becomes visible on the same page in descending order, now my question is how can i handle synchronous updates  meaning if multiple users are using the same app at the same time  and if anybody inserts something using the form than does angular provides a way that other users will get updated data at the same time, I am confused with this functionality. Please help

Answer (score 0):

1) You will need to use a form of some type to capture the information and either store it locally on the front-end, or if you want to persist the information, then create a back-end server to store this information.

2)  If you are talking about two users using the login form at the same time, there is no synchronous issue, because each form is rendered in the user's browser, and is therefore independent and one user's login form will not interact at all with another user's login form. If you want a page that shows who is logged in and who is not, then you will want to use websockets to allow 2 way communication between the front-end and the back-end in real time.